# How to identify file for "The system cannot find the file specified." during a pg_ctl -D start?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2, troubleshooting

I'm getting one message during pg_ctl -D start of the standby server. Perhaps more of a general troubleshooting question.

This is what I'm seeing when I do a `pg_ctl -D start`:

```
D:\>pg_ctl -D d:\dev_data_standby start
server starting
D:\>2016-03-21 08:41:12 EDT   1016 LOG:  loaded library "auto_explain"
        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The log file shows:

```
2016-03-21 08:41:12 EDT   3564 LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-03-21 08:38:08 EDT
2016-03-21 08:41:16 EDT   3564 LOG:  entering standby mode
2016-03-21 08:41:16 EDT   3564 LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000002000000F2" from archive
2016-03-21 08:41:16 EDT   3564 LOG:  redo starts at 2/F2000020
2016-03-21 08:41:16 EDT   3564 LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 2/F20000E0
2016-03-21 08:41:16 EDT   3816 LOG:  streaming replication successfully connected to primary
```

How can I troubleshoot that error:  `The system cannot find the file specified.`?